# How do I generate a table of cofactors from minors of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, table

I'm trying to figure out how to find the determinant of a 5x5 matrix by co-factor expansion in the second row.  I have already calculated the minors of the matrix using `Minors`. I'm also trying to figure out how to generate the cofactors of the minor matrices using the `Table` command.

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 2},
     {4, 4, 3, 2, 1}};

Amin = Minors[A]
(* {{-20, -22, 0, 10, 12}, {-22, -37, -16, 11, 10}, {0, -16, -32, -16, 0},
    {10, 11, -16, -37, -22}, {12, 10, 0, -22, -20}} *)
```

Could someone give me step-by-step instructions or concepts to solve this problem?
To emphasize, please note that I am only asking for instructions.

Comment: Maybe something like `Times[A, KroneckerProduct[#, #] &[(-1)^Range[Length[A]]]]` would do?

Comment: I want to understand with step by step instructions.

Comment: `(-1)^Range[Length[A]]` produces the vector `{-1, 1, -1, 1, -1}`. Taking the `KroneckerProduct` turns this into a matrix of alternating sings. `Times` just multiplies each entry of `A` with the corresponding sign.

Comment: Check [`Minors` reference guide page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html), Properties & Relations section second and third examples.

Comment: How would i create a table of cofactors first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `Cofactor` and `CofactorMatrix` functions:

```
Cofactor[m_?MatrixQ, {i_Integer, j_Integer}] := (-1)^(i + j)* 
Det[Delete[Thread@Delete[m, {i}], {j}]]

CofactorMatrix[m_?MatrixQ] := 
Table[Cofactor[m, {i, j}], {i, #}, {j, #}] &@Length@m
```

Next, we define the `DetByCofactorExpansion` function:

```
DetByCofactorExpansion[mat_?MatrixQ, row_Integer] := 
CofactorMatrix[mat][[row]] . mat[[row]]

DetByCofactorExpansion[A, 2]

(*32*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You already got the minors.

Then the determinant of a matrix can be obtained by the Laplace expansion (see e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). Here is an example:

```
laplDet[mat_, row_] := 
  Sum[(-1)^(row + j)  Amin[[row, j]]  mat[[row, j]], {j, Length[mat]}];
laplDet[A, 2]

32
```

Comment: How would i create a table of cofactors first?

Comment: The Laplace expansion is an expansion in minors with weights (cofactors) given by corresponding matrix elements of the original matrix with alternating signs.